# The "‘" character turns into "?" character using laravel

Tags: php, regex, laravel

Many people copies/pastes text/data from msword, actually into web forms. 

The standart upper coma character is " ' " this but msword's upper coma is " ‘ " so that lead some problems like turning into "?" character after posting the data.


Is there any way to prevent this rather than using functions like string replacement or regular expressions ?

Comment: It's called *handling encodings correctly.*

Comment: your databases collation is most likely incorrect